# difference between __setattr__ and __dict__

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I want to set an attribute for a instance：

I can use `__setattr__(key, value)` *or* `self.__dict__[key]=value`

I want to know how `__setattr__` works, if `__setattr__` just set the k,v in `__dict__`, whats the differencet between two ways? What is the meaning of setattr's existence？

Comment: You should use `setattr(key, value)`.

Comment: Having two underscores at the beginning and the end of a name is a strong indicator that it should not be used directly.

Comment: "I want to know how __setattr__ works" What happened when you tried looking it up in the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__setattr__(key, value)` is the function which gets called by `setattr(instance, key, value)`.

`__setattr__(key, value)` typically will act the same as `self.__dict__[key]= value` unless the class the `__setattr__` method in the function has been overridden in some way.

This might help: [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/setattr.html)

```js
class MyClass(object):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print(f"setting {key}={value}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyClass()
    m.a = 3
    m.b = 6
    m.__dict__.update({"c": 7})
    print(f"{m.c=}")
    print(f"{m.__dict__=}")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

while `__dict__` is an internal dictionary that holds all of their internal variables, `__setattr__` is actually a method that is always called when you try to set an attribute, and therefore, you can intercept these actions and act according.

A sample code can help you to understand the difference:

```
class Foo:
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print(f'Setting {key} to {value}')
        self.__dict__[key] = value

f = Foo()
f.__dict__['test'] = 1
f.__setattr__('test', 2)
f.test = 3
```

The output would be:

```
Setting test to 2
Setting test to 3
```

And the reason is that by accessing `__dict__`, you are directly accessing the internal object dictionary and the `__setattr__` method is skipped.